# kotlin-android error when using Android Studio 3.2 Canary 17

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

Just updated to Android Studio 3.2 Canary 17 and now getting following error:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':some_module`.
> 'kotlin-android' expects one of the Android Gradle plugins to be applied to the project:
>
> ```
>     * android
>     * com.android.application
>     * android-library
>     * com.android.library
>     * com.android.test
>     * com.android.feature
>     * com.android.dynamic-feature
> ```

The `build.gradle` for that module includes:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

The project includes several modules composed of mixture of `com.android.application`, `com.android.feature`, and `com.android.instantapp`

Comment: Yep, it's probably a bad build, and they are aware of it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109893035

Comment: Thanks @TWL, I see following comment earlier in related issue so hopefully there'll be build available soon with this fixed.  "We are going to revert the change and release a new build."

Comment: Last update short while ago in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109894102 in response to question on timing of release with fix: "As soon as we can but probably a few days at least unfortunately."

Comment: I have the exact same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in Canary 18 which is out now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error comes from your instant app module. It's happening the same to me for dynamic feature modules. I opened an issue [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109923680).

If you have a look to your log, it's only affecting to instant / dynamic feature modules:

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: 'kotlin-android' expects one of the Android Gradle plugins to be applied to the project:
        * android
        * com.android.application
        * android-library
        * com.android.library
        * com.android.test
        * com.android.feature
        * com.android.dynamic-feature      <-------`

and from your log:

`* android
    * com.android.application
    * android-library
    * com.android.library
    * com.android.test
    * com.android.feature
    * com.android.dynamic-feature   <-----`

I guess they will be fixing it soon :-) Since it's kind of a big deal, he.